# php and apache not seeing anything in there defined tmp dirs

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, cron

we have standard php and apache but not seeing anything in there defined tmp dirs
How to check logs for non application 500s?

I have actually 2 issues one is routing logs for https://www.test.com

other is that the '/tmp/' or our dev on system currently is writing to a private system dir

e.g. /tmp/systemd-private-840c0bc8008041628bfc86e69a7bb944-httpd.service-z3oDEZ/tmp/

our old server wrote to '/tmp/' without the 'systemd-...' additions

I also have an issue with the '/tmp' directory storing things to private directories based on service executing the request rather than the. '/tmp' root. Do anyone help me how can resolve that?

We have CRONs that require static tmp dir is there a way to have the tmp be created consistently

From the answers like
serverfault.com/a/912098/984089

So i understand that '/etc/systemd/system/[name-goes-here].service.d/config_name.conf' should not already exist, right?

that file doesn't exist on our old server and the 'tmp' issue isn't present there is there some other way this is configured/can be?

any short of help would be apricated ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is the 'private temporary directory' feature from newer systemd versions. it's a security feature where services are assigned to isolated temporary space instead of the global linux system `/tmp.`

In order to disable this for your apache service and get apache2 viewing the whole /tmp:

1. Stop your apache2 service: `systemctl stop apache2`
2. Go to your apache2 service configuration file: `nano /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service`
3. Comment out the `PrivateTmp=true` directive in this file.
4. Save the file and reload the configuration: `systemctl daemon-reload`
5. Finally restart your apache service: `systemctl start apache2`

Now, the Apache tmp root directory shall be the global linux /tmp directory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I recommend _not_ doing it this way. Instead, a drop-in configuration is the way to go: It will persist even when the package is upgraded, which will replace whatever the `*.wants/some.service` symlink points at.

Comment: @Daniel B ,  I did try other way (serverfault.com/a/912098/984089) won't work, could you pl describe a bit ?

Comment: That Tmp file doesn't exist on our old server and the 'tmp' issue isn't present there , is there some other way this is configured/can be? We have CRONs that require static tmp dir.

Comment: This is not a 'tmp issue' but a new 'systemd security feature'. So, this 'logically' doesnt exist in your 'old' server with an 'old' systemd. If you don't like my above suggestion and want to break your head a little more :) , you may try to customize your CRON script for in order to reach your file with something like that: `find /tmp/systemd-private*apache2*/ -type f -name *MYSUPERFILE.txt*`

Comment: @petitradisgris, Thanks, yes, commenting out worked charm, Hopefully, it won't cause any issues with the feature.

Comment: nice. Enjoy. in the future, try considering updating your project to take this feature in account :)